# TEXT formula returns error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Why does =TEXT(16,"TEMP000") return a #VALUE error?
I am trying to get TEMP016 as the result.

I have tried it with other alphanumeric examples, like =TEXT(16, A092000) which should show A092016, and it works fine there.

Comment: remove the quotes from TEMP000

Answer (score 2):

The counting of double quotes can be a pain.  Use:

```
=TEXT(16,"""TEMP""000")
```

[image]